# Need help in Confusion matrix with python in CNN model

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, scikit-learn

Can you help me to display a confusion matrix from a CNN model executed on a dataset of 40 classes.
I'm stuck I tried several methods but it doesn't work.
I tried to use the loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' and loss='categorical_crossentropy' parameters but without result. Please, if there is someone who can help me to find a solution I will be grateful

Here is my code

```
   def create_model(input_shape=None):
        if input_shape is None :
           input_shape=(48,48,1)
    
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(6, (5, 5), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='same', activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(40, activation = 'softmax'))
    
        return model

HOG_history = HOG_model.fit(X_train_HOG, y_train, batch_size=8 , 
                            epochs=50, 
                            validation_data = (X_test_HOG, y_test))


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from keras.utils import np_utils
import itertools    

#print(predicted)
#print(y_test)
ynew = HOG_model.predict_classes(X_test_HOG)


Acc=accuracy_score(y_test, ynew)
print("accuracy : ")
print(Acc)
#/tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(np.array(y_test), ynew).ravel()
cnf_matrix=confusion_matrix(np.array(y_test), ynew)

y_test1 = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 20)



def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                                                  cmap=plt.cm.cool):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    SMALL_SIZE = 24
    MEDIUM_SIZE = 28
    BIGGER_SIZE = 30
    plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
    plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
    plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
    plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
    plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
    plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
    plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        #print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    #print(cm)
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.show()


print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')
print(cnf_matrix)

plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix[1:20,1:20], 
            classes=['s1','s10','s11','s12','s13','s14','s15','s16','s17',
                             's18',
                             's19',
                             's2',
                             's20',
                             's21',
                             's22',
                             's23',
                             's24',
                             's25',
                             's26',
                             's27',
                             's28',
                             's29',
                             's3',
                             's30',
                             's31',
                             's32',
                             's33',
                             's34',
                             's35',
                             's36',
                             's37',
                             's38',
                             's39',
                             's4',
                             's40',
                             's5',
                             's6',
                             's7',
                             's8',
                             's9'],
                      title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')

print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % confusion_matrix(np.array(y_test), ynew))
print(classification_report(np.array(y_test), ynew))

ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, it is preferable to tag the libraries that one is trying to use (`matplotlib` or `keras`) rather than the infrastructure (`anaconda` or `jupyter-notebook`). Unless the question is about the infrastructure in particular, it suffices to mention the infrastructure as part of the question in something like a "System Details" section.

Comment: thank you very much for these remarks it's the first time I post a question that's why